# Getting stripe payment intent method error

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

The below code in javascript works and it returns the response with payment method e.g 'pm_1HZDptHMQMk5h2YU0kai****', I used this payment method to collect the payment and the response from the stripe is below.

"The provided PaymentMethod was previously used with a PaymentIntent without Customer attachment, shared with a connected account without Customer attachment, or was detached from a Customer. It may not be used again. To use a PaymentMethod multiple times, you must attach it to a Customer first".

The issue I could not figure out that I haven't used the paymentMethod anywhere. but it still is giving me the above message.

By the way I tried with `setup_future_usage: 'on_session' and 'off_session' values`.

```
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51H1xOmHMQMk5h2YUX7ShAMdjy9************************');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#32325d",
  }
};

var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#card-element");
card.on('change', ({error}) => {
  const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (error) {
    displayError.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  stripe.confirmCardPayment('pi_1HZDaPHMQMk5h2YUga3QwB2E******************', {
    payment_method: {
      card: card,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jony',
      }
    },
    setup_future_usage: 'on_session'
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        console.log(result);
      // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      // The payment has been processed!
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
          alert('success');
        // Show a success message to your customer
        // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback
        // execution. Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the
        // payment_intent.succeeded event that handles any business critical
        // post-payment actions.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the PaymentMethod separately (before you actually use it for a PaymentIntent), you should follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

If you want to create the PaymentMethod and charge it via a PaymentIntent in one swing, you should follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

> By the way I tried with setup_future_usage: 'on_session' and 'off_session' values.

That works if you're following the second link above, but not with a PaymentMethod that already existed and was consumed in some way.

Comment: I have followed the exact link the first one, can you be specific to the exact line.

Comment: One key thing you'd want to make sure of is that you're providing a `customer` for the SetupIntent.